# Creating a library file with version number but allow it to work with any project

Tags: c#, android, dll, libraries

the title probably doesn't make much sense as to what I am trying to achieve, its kind of difficult to explain in a brief bit of text.

I have created a project both in C# for Windows/Mono projects and an Android version of the library.

When I upload the library to my server for users to download and use in their own projects I want the library to have the following sort of name

```
MyLibrary_Version.1.0.dll for Windows
MyLibrary_Version.1.0.jar for Android
```

When the project is built and the library is referenced it is referenced using the name `MyLibrary.dll` or `MyLibrary.jar`.

I'm not sure how I can ensure that each project that is referenced by my library can work OK when it has a different name, i.e. include the version number.

This must be possible, as other companies who provide library do the same sort of thing but I can't see anyway how this can be done.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the response your looking for, but here goes...

in your c# project in the properties folder, edit your assemblyinfo.cs file and add a version numberin there like..

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

The * will increment the count by 1 each time you build.

When your app consumes the dll, you should be able to specify the matching version of the dll, in the assembly declaration for that dll in the app.config. (if using provider model)

Or through reflection in your code to return an error if the incorrect DLL is included in with App release.